# Audio from vimeo video continues after modal has closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have a vimeo video that plays in a modal window. It works just fine in every browser except for safari (haven't tested it in internet explorer). In safari, closing the window hides the video but doesn't stop audio playback.

I'm using bpopup:jquery.bpopup.min.js
And jquery 1.10.2

This is the link that triggers the modal window:

```
<li id="li1"><a href="#">Reel</a></li>
```

And the jquery that opens the video:

```
 <script>
// $ is assigned to jQuery
 ;(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('#li1').bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#reel').bPopup({
                modalClose: true,
                opacity: 0.6,
                positionStyle: 'fixed' //'fixed' or 'absolute
});});});})(jQuery);
    </script>
```

And the video itself:

```
<div id="reel">
    <a class="b-close">X<a/>
     <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/86850935?byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=c9ff23" width="500" height="334" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

I'm fairly new to jquery, and I've spent the last few days stumbling around in an effort to solve this problem to no avail.

Edit: my select styling-

```
<style>

body{
font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;
color:#FFF; 
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:#000;
}


#reel{ 
display:none; 
}
.b-close{
cursor:pointer;
position:absolute;
right:-20px;
top:0px;
width:10px;
height:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to setup some logic on the `onClose` callback within bPopup (see section 4: http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/). One option is to use the Vimeo JavaScript API: http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api

Another option is to reset the iframe `src`. Here is some example JavaScript that accomplishes that:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#li1').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#reel').bPopup({
        modalClose: true,
        opacity: 0.6,
        positionStyle: 'fixed', //'fixed' or 'absolute
        onClose: function() {
          var iframe = $('#reel iframe'),
              iframe_src = iframe.attr('src');

          iframe.attr('src', '');
          iframe.attr('src', iframe_src);
        }
    });
  });
});
```